# DataTemplate Binding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am having a problem trouble shooting a binding error in a datatemplate. I create an observable collection, and set mySelectFlag True for each filename. When the Datagrid displays, the checkbox on the header is checked, and each row in the datagrid has its checkbox checked. If I select/unselect a row checkbox, the change shows up on the observable collection. If I uncheck the header checkbox, I set each record on the observable collection to false. I call OnPropertyChanged on the observable collection, but the datagrid does not reflect the change. There are no binding errors. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much.

I have a class:

```
public class InputFileName
        {
            public bool mySelectFlag { get; set; }
            public string myFileName { get; set; }
        }
```

and a ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<InputFileName> _DisplayList;
public ObservableCollection<InputFileName> DisplayList
{
     get { return _DisplayList; }
     set
     {
         if (value != _DisplayList)
         {
             _DisplayList = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("DisplayList");
         }
     }
 }
```

and this is my xaml:

```
<DataGrid
     Margin="25"
     RowHeaderWidth="0"
     AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro"
     AlternationCount="2"
     Block.TextAlignment="Center"
     CanUserAddRows="False"
     CanUserReorderColumns="False"
     CanUserResizeColumns="False"
     CanUserSortColumns="False"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayList}" >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                         <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                              <Setter.Value>
                                   <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox
                                             IsChecked="{Binding                Path=DataContext.IsSelected, ElementName=myControl1, FallbackValue=False}"
                                                        Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectAllRows, ElementName=myControl1}"
                                                        Content="Select"
                                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                                        Width="Auto" />
                                     </DataTemplate>
                                  </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                             </Style>
                             </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=mySelectFlag, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=False}"
                                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TestTaskCommand, ElementName=myControl1}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=SelectedIndex}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn
                                Header="File Name"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=myFileName}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `InputFileName` class as weill to make changes visible to UI -

```
private bool mySelectFlag;
public bool MySelectFlag
{
   get
   {
      return mySelectFlag;
   }
   set
   {
      mySelectFlag = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("MySelectFlag");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

INotifyPropertyChanged interfaceto be implemented by your class, a method should be defined like the one below and all the properties should call the OnPropertyChangeEvent

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

```
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e));
    }
```